# Issue with transformation main.py in main.exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I wrote the program in pyCharm. The program interface was created through PyQt5.
In pyCharm, the code runs and works properly. But when I transforming my main.py in main.exe with pyinstaller/auto py to exe, it does not work. Actually programm is starting, but when I trying download workfile in *.xlsx format, programm is going crash.
How can I figure out what the problem is? Trying start main.exe in cmd, but it does not push the error, just end work.

````
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QTextEdit, QAction)
import pandas as pd

def main_foo(x):
    book = pd.read_excel(x, engine='openpyxl')
    column_one = book.columns.tolist()[0]
    column_two = book.columns.tolist()[1]
    column_three = book.columns.tolist()[2]
    column_four = book.columns.tolist()[3]
    num_slice = []
    for i in range(book.shape[0]):
        if str(book[column_one][i]).replace(" ", '').lower() == 'материалы' or str(book[column_two][i]).replace(" ", '').lower() == 'материалы' or str(book[column_three][i]).replace(" ", '').lower() == 'материалы':
            num_slice.append(i)
        elif str(book[column_one][i]).replace(" ", '').lower() == 'итого"материалы"' or str(book[column_two][i]).replace(" ", '').lower() == 'итого"материалы"':
            num_slice.append(i)
            break

    ws = []

    for i in range(num_slice[0] + 1, num_slice[1]):
        ws.append([str(book[column_one][i]), str(book[column_two][i]), str(book[column_three][i]), str(book[column_four][i])])
    df = pd.DataFrame(ws, columns=['code', 'name', 'unit', 'amount'])

    electrodes = 0

    'расчет электродов'

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if str(row['name']).lower().find('электрод') == 0:
            if str(row['unit']).lower() == 'кг':
                electrodes += float(row['amount']) / 1000
            elif str(row['unit']).lower() == 'т':
                electrodes += float(row['amount'])

    electrodes = round(electrodes, 3)
    message = f"Масса электродов: {electrodes} т\n"
    print(message)

    return message

class Resource_sheet(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), 'Открыть...', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Открыть файл')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        menubar.setObjectName('menu')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Файл')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Разбор сводной ресурсной ведомости')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '', "Все файлы Excel (*.xlsx)")[0]
        try:
            a = str(main_foo(fname))
            """Тут можно будет в дальнейшем вставить код для анализа текста, который мы получаем из главной функции и выгрузки его допустим в word"""
            self.textEdit.setText(a)

        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        except UnboundLocalError:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            msg.setText('Код ошибки №2')
            msg.setInformativeText('Выбран неверный формат файла')
            msg.setStyleSheet("width")
            msg.setWindowTitle('Ошибка')
            msg.setGeometry(350, 350, 500, 500)
            msg.exec_()
        except IndexError:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            msg.setText('Ошибка')
            msg.setInformativeText('Возможно, выбран неверный формат файла')
            msg.setWindowTitle('Ошибка')
            msg.setGeometry(350, 350, 500, 500)
            msg.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Resource_sheet()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

input()```
````

Comment: What is the error you are getting, how is it crashing?

Comment: @r_batra, I’m put it wrong. It’s not error it just closing the app.

Comment: Are you sure, your excel file have these many number of columns? It might be breaking because excel file has less number of columns or range elements than you are defining?

Comment: @r_batra, this is a template. I repeat, the code works fine in the pyCharm.